# Scala: (Array[Int],Array[Int]) => Array[Int] by +

Tags: arrays, scala, indexoutofboundsexception

So, I want to 'merge' two Array[Int] by adding the value of the same index.
It should be like:

```
newarray(0) = array1(0)+array2(0)...
f.e. Array(1,2,3)+Array(1,1,1,1,1) = Array(2,3,4,1,1)
```

I wrote:

```
(array1, array2).zipped.map(_+_)
```

But this obviously throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsexception when 
array1.length != array2.length .

I'm also looking for the **smartest** and **shortest** solution possible.

Comment: You should tell us what you want in the result array when the input arrays are different lengths.

Comment: i want the not existing values be filled up with 0

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion to get you started could be something like this:

```
val v1 = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
val v2 = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val v3 = v1.zip(v2).map(_+_)
println(s"V3: $v3")
```

This will yield the following output, where the last element of v2 is ignored:

```
V3: List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

However, if you want to default to a specific value, you can use zipAll, like this:

```
val v1 = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
val v2 = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val v3 = v1.zipAll(v2, 0, 0).map(_+_)
println(s"V3: $v3")
```

Which will give you the following output, where the shorter array is padded with a value of zero:

```
V3: List(2, 4, 6, 8, 5)
```

EDIT: I see you clarified your question a bit. It seems like you're looking for the second option, using zipAll.